# Cannot identify strange ‘ringing’ noise right towards the end of Mahler’s 8th Symphony

Tags: classical-music, identify-this-effect

There’s a strange ‘ringing’ — best word I can use to describe the sound — right at the end of [Mahler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gustav_Mahler)’s [8th Symphony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symphony_No._8_(Mahler)), and I can’t work out if it’s woodwinds or another family, although it doesn’t sound like the strings.

> [MAHLER | Symphony no. 8 | Netherlands Philharmonic Orchestra | Marc Albrecht | Concertgebouw](https://m.youtube.com/watch?feature=share&v=nxf3xtH31jA)
>
> *Symphony no. 8 by Gustav Mahler performed by the Netherlands Philharmonic Orchestra with chief conductor Marc Albrecht. Recorded at the Concertgebouw, Amsterdam on Saturday February 23 2019.*

You can hear it right at the epic ending, specially after the cymbal crashes starting at 01:25:36 and again, rather quite loudly, right before the finish.

See I can’t tell if it’s the recording, it could just be the huge amount of power going through nearly every single instrument. I can swear I can still hear something albeit not as loudly mind in other recordings.

Comment: If it's the same thing that I heard, then I think that it's either the flutes or the flutes in sustained resonance with the other woodwinds (oboe and english horn?).  Can you identify the pitch?

Comment: I’m afraid I cannot be very precise but it’s of a high pitch most certainly. Some form of a vibrato may indicate such noise. At least you can hear it too.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Whatever you're hearing has nothing to do with the oboes, there's no way they'll be audible against everything else. The four flutes and the E-flat clarinet on the high G might be audible, but they're not going to 'resonate' with anything. The brass and the organ dominate the sound.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This it the last page of the score.

[image]

That's a lot of noise. I have no idea what you are hearing, but I can't hear anything that's not in the score. You might possibly be hearing the organ which enters on the previous page. Mahler writes "Volles Werk" (full organ: all stops out) over the entry, but it's possible that the organist saves a couple of stops and adds them thirteen bars before the end.